# Planning tool JQuery / MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-widgets

The webapplication I would like to build gives the user the possibility to select a period on a calendar. On the selected days they can write the start and end hour. The total amount of hours gets calculated. On the image below you can see what I would like to accomplish. What is a good way to get started programming this? Is there a good tutorial to get me started?

Is there a JQuery widget that gives a good start?

On the left you got some Employees and for each of them the user can select the period and fill in the hours they have to work.

[image]

I hope u get the idea that i have in mind. Please feel free to ask me any specifications.

I'm using MVC 4 - razor pages for the webapp

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmmm well I dont believe there is a jQuery widget that does exactly what you say but you could use the date picker in this for sure.

Comment: Check out the [jQuery FullCalendar plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), it should help you get started.

Comment: @VimalStan that is a badass plugin!

Comment: @SoonDead It most definitely is :)

Answer (score 0):

I've made something very similar in a MVC2 app with jQuery to check schedules for formative actions.

I first place a temporary span for the action and load it into the calendar provided by jQuery's datepicker, later I overwrite it's onSelect event to affect and save my data.

So when I click on a day of the calendar (only days on the previously selected time span are clickable) I allow user to introduce data for the schedule on that day.

Data saving to server is managed through AJAX calls that saves during using interaction.